# Problema con form-data con Java (JIRA)

Tags: java, api, rest, jira

Estoy tratando de conectarme a la API de Jira, desde Java para subir un archivo adjunto. EL problema es que la solicitud siempre me da 400. Ya he hecho otras conexiones y siempre me funciona, el tema creo que porque está utiliza form-data. inicialmente me daba errores 500, pero probando desde postman ***(donde si funciona)*** le fui añadiendo los headers hasta que llegué a un 400.

En postman funciona

y este es mi código

```
package com.mycompany.testjira;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class SubirArchivo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String apiUrl = "https://xxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/PTCH-17/attachments";
        String authToken = "Basic abcs0.1234";

        // Crea un cliente HTTP
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        // Crea una solicitud POST
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(apiUrl);

        // Agrega encabezados a la solicitud
        httpPost.addHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", authToken);
        httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpPost.addHeader("Postman-Token", "b057ae51-51eb-48a3-8900-3b077cfb8130");
        httpPost.addHeader("Host", "xxx.atlassian.net");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        httpPost.addHeader("Cookie", "atlassian.xsrf.token=61992f6e629ada26e96f226_lin");
        
        
        // Agrega datos en formato form-data al cuerpo de la solicitud
        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("C:/Users/felipefarias/Profile.pdf"), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file");

        httpPost.setEntity(entityBuilder.build());

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // Imprime la respuesta
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("Response Body:");
        System.out.println(responseToString(response));

        // Cierra recursos
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    private static String responseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            return result.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Alguna idea? :( he probado de todo y nada me funciona.